# how to access html element by name and change another attribute?

Tags: jquery, html

in my HTML I have the Element :
`<element name="name123" config="some config"></element>`

What would be the way to access my element "BY NAME which is name123" and modify the content of "config" attribute after the element is loaded?

Comment: `$('[name="name123"]')`. Also don't make up your own attributes. Use the custom data attribute instead: `data-config="some config"`.

Comment: add an id="name123" to your element then you can call it in jquery like $("#name123").(do what you want hear)

Comment: It is Not my Choice to add attributes to an element in this page.

Comment: I think the Question was Clear When I specified the Access should be by name attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Use [attribute-equals-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to get elements by attribute along with `.attr()` to set the attribute value:

```
$('[name=name123]').attr('config','newcofighere')
```

Comment: I just forgot to mention, I meant after the Element is loaded.

Comment: wrap the code in dom ready and if you are adding dynamically,then after appending it.